# How to get rid of multiple left join in EF core eager loading for same tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm converting Oracle Sp to EFCore with eager loading but I wonder that how to convert below query with more efficiently.

My main aim is code it more clean and learn a better way if it's possible. It's leads to create many MRC_BATCH_INFO instances for .Include() which is not I want.

```sql
              SELECT C.COLL_ID,
                MI.MRC_INC_NAME,
                ME.MRC_EXC_NAME,
                SI.STR_INC_NAME,
                SE.STR_EXC_NAME,
                AI.MSTR_INC_NAME,
                AE.MSTR_EXC_NAME,
                FROM MERCHANT C
               ,MRC_BATCH_INFO MI
               ,MRC_BATCH_INFO ME
               ,MRC_BATCH_INFO SI
               ,MRC_BATCH_INFO SE
               ,MRC_BATCH_INFO AI
               ,MRC_BATCH_INFO AE
              WHERE C.COLL_ID = PI_COLL_ID
                AND C.MRC_INC_LIST_ID = MI.COLL_MRC_BATCH_ID(+)
                AND C.MRC_EXC_LIST_ID = ME.COLL_MRC_BATCH_ID(+)
                AND C.STR_INC_LIST_ID = SI.COLL_MRC_BATCH_ID(+)
                AND C.STR_EXC_LIST_ID = SE.COLL_MRC_BATCH_ID(+)
                AND C.MSTR_INC_LIST_ID = AI.COLL_MRC_BATCH_ID(+)
                AND C.MSTR_EXC_LIST_ID = AE.COLL_MRC_BATCH_ID(+)
```

as

```
var result = await _mrcRepository
             .Include(x=>x.MrcBatchInfo_MI)  // I want to get rid of these LeftJ
             .Include(x=>x.MrcBatchInfo_ME)  // reduce it as one if it's possible
             .Include(x=>x.MrcBatchInfo_SI)  // or any other optimization
             .Include(x=>x.MrcBatchInfo_SE)
             .Include(x=>x.MrcBatchInfo_AI)
             .Include(x=>x.MrcBatchInfo_AE)
             .Where(x=>x.CollId==collId)
             //.Select( ) in this part and its OK 
             .ToListAsync();
```

Thx for any comment.

Comment: So what do you want?

Comment: You can only remove a join if it is not needed in the SELECT.  If your select has an item from each of the 6 tables than you need 6 joins.  If your SELECT is only getting data from 3 tables than you need 3 joins.

Comment: If you have `Select` at the end, you can remove ALL Includes.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft first of all,I just wanna know if any other better way from "you" expert guys.

Comment: @jdweng thank you for explanation I ignited and commited it.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv why ,I didn't get it?

Comment: @UtkuYıldız, because `Include` and `Select` are mutual exclusive operators.

Comment: You could `context.MERCHANT.Where(...)...` then build a hashset of the returned id's, and run your own 2nd query `context.MRC_BATCH_INFO.Where(x => ids.Any(i => i == x.COLL_MRC_BATCH_ID))...` and let the change tracker link everything together. Otherwise, you should refactor your info table to flip the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

`Include` and `Select` serve different purposes. While `Include` results in `JOIN` in the queries, it is *not* required for EF to perform joins, instead it is used for Eager Loading related data when you want to load an entire entity graph. (An entity and it's related entities)

`Select` on the other hand is for handling a concept called Projection. In these cases you aren't necessarily returning entities, but rather telling EF to use it's entities and their relations to populate a desired output.

So for example, if the data you want is something that your method would return, we would create a POCO DTO object or ViewModel to hold that desired output data:

```
[Serializable]
public class MerchantDTO
{
    public int CollId { get; set; }
    public string MRC_INC_NAME { get; set; }
    public string MRC_EXC_NAME { get; set; }
    public string STR_INC_NAME { get; set; }
    public string STR_EXC_NAME { get; set; }
    public string MSTR_INC_NAME { get; set; }
    public string MSTR_EXC_NAME { get; set; }
```

}

From here we can build a `Select` clause to load a DTO from the merchant entity graph, and EF can work out the related data via navigation properties. The advantage of this is that the resulting SQL will only pull back the data from the relevant tables that it needs, rather than everything from the Merchant and related tables.

```
var result = await _context.Merchants
    .Where(x=>x.CollId==collId)
    .Select(x => new MerchantDTO
    {
        CollId = x.CollId,
        MRC_INC_NAME = x.MrcBatchInfo_MI.Name,
        MRC_EXE_NAME = x.MrcBatchInfo_ME.Name,
        STR_INC_NAME = x.MrcBatchInfo_SI.Name,
        STR_INC_NAME = x.MrcBatchInfo_SE.Name,
        MSTR_INC_NAME = x.MrcBatchInfo_AI.Name,
        MSTR_INC_NAME = x.MrcBatchInfo_AE.Name
    }).ToListAsync();
```

... using more appropriate naming convention and I guessed at the details like Name property to be returned. EF will still generate Joins and such behind the scenes so don't expect it to mimic an existing query, but for the most part performance wise the queries that EF generates are pretty good.

There may be complex cases that can be optimized more explicitly in which case an option is to leverage Views and mapping entities to the view rather than the base tables. (good for complex read operations)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
AND C.MRC_INC_LIST_ID = MI.COLL_MRC_BATCH_ID(+)
AND C.MRC_EXC_LIST_ID = ME.COLL_MRC_BATCH_ID(+)
AND C.STR_INC_LIST_ID = SI.COLL_MRC_BATCH_ID(+)
AND C.STR_EXC_LIST_ID = SE.COLL_MRC_BATCH_ID(+)
AND C.MSTR_INC_LIST_ID = AI.COLL_MRC_BATCH_ID(+)
AND C.MSTR_EXC_LIST_ID = AE.COLL_MRC_BATCH_ID(+)
```

Personally, I think your database design is backwards.

Rather than having a `MERCHANT` table with 6 foreign keys to the same table. You need a table with a FK to `MERCHANT`, and a type column to represent the 6 (or more) types. This would either be on the `MRC_BATCH_INFO` table, or on a new many-to-many join table, depending on how these two tables are related.